# Terraform Module creation from a AWS extract

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have adopted 13 AWS environments. I would like to standardise with Infrastructure as code as they can all be same but the have 62 unique resources in each environment.

Plan is to use a module approach, the same Terraform code but have different env var per resource type and have gitlab to orchestrate. Single or multiple resources as required

In this scenario, we want to be able to declare variables that gives resource selection control.

I have created massive terraform.tf files around 22000 lines per environment using former2. These have all the variables in for current infra.

Is there a script or method in Terraform?

1. Automatically write the generic 62 modules
2. Extract the variables into tfvars file.

For example

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "Route53RecordSet28" {
name = "uat.mot.mydom.com."
type = "NS"
ttl = 3600
records = [
    "ns-112804.awsdns-33.co.uk",
    "ns-22170.awsdns-33.com",
    "ns-133349.awsdns-40.org",
    "ns-73554.awsdns-28.net"
]
zone_id = "Z26YKH2332323ZQNFYBI"
```

would create set of files a main, output and variables.tf files from the standard HASICORP registry and also create a tfvars file to use with the tf files.